# Making session component not case sensitive in java

Tags: java, session, case-sensitive

For a project i'm working in Jdeveloper version 12.1.3.0.0 in ADF.
I am trying to make a connection with a file via a session component. Down below my code. The session component is case sensitive. My question is how i can make this component non-case sensitive.

```
errorMessage = getResource("Can_t_connect_to_this_server_with_this_port_with_this_connection_type");
        session = jsch.getSession(user, server, port);
        session.setPassword(pass);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();

        errorMessage = getResource("Ftp_folder_path_couldn_t_be_found");
        String ftpFolder = configRow.getFtpFolder();
        if (ftpFolder != null) {
            ftpFolder = ftpFolder.replace("\\", "/");
            File folderDir=new File(ftpFolder);
                if (!folderDir.isDirectory() && folderDir.exists()) {
                    String htmlMessage = "<html><body>" + errorMessage + "</body></html>";
                    //String htmlMessage = "<html><body>Server could not be reached.<BR><BR>" + e.toString() + "</body></html>";
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "", htmlMessage));
                    testResult = false;
                }

        }
```

thanks in advance.

Hidde van Werkhoven

Comment: I could not get at which point you want case-insensitivity. User? Pass? Config?

Comment: W want case-insensitivity on Config.